# How to receive array data using this code?

Tags: jquery

This is live search script. Livesearch works fine but can't get every array data. I would like to get each searchComponent's  'name' and 'code' and 'location' data.

> UPDATE

Here is js whole code.

https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/wyejqhsz/3/

> I already have $data array so I would like to ADD those items INTO IT.

```
<div id="searchComponent-1">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 1" class="search form-control" size="3000"
               onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
        <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-group result"></ul>
</div>
<div id="searchComponent-2">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 2" class="search form-control" size="3000"
               onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13"/>
        <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group result"></ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' + name + '">');
searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="code" value="' + code + '">');
searchWrapper.find('.result').after('<input type="hidden" name="location" value="' + location + '">');


$(document).ready(function () {
   //then apply same method on each element
    $("#searchComponent-1").searchAndDisplay(); 
    $("#searchComponent-2").searchAndDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assumed your dom will have input data like this:**

```
  <ul class="list-group result">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Name2">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="Code2">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="Location2">
  </ul>
```

**You can do as the following to get the desired result:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result_array = []
  $('.result').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find("input[name='name']").val();
    var code = $(this).find("input[name='code']").val();
    var location = $(this).find("input[name='location']").val();
    result_array.push([name, code, location])
  });

  console.log('As Array:')
  console.log(result_array)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchComponent-1">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 1" class="search form-control" size="3000" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
    <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-group result">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Name1">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="Code1">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="Location1">
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="searchComponent-2">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="input 2" class="search form-control" size="3000" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" />
    <span class="searchclear glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-group result">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Name2">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="Code2">
    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="Location2">
  </ul>
</div>
```

**If you want your result in One Dimensional Array you can do:**

```
result_array.push(name, code, location)
```

**Output will be:**

```
["Name1", "Code1", "Location1", "Name2", "Code2", "Location2"]
```

Comment: `<input>` is invalid child of `<ul>`

Comment: @charlietfl Nevertheless the HTML does not throw an error if you have `input` inside the `ul` Right?

and he seems to have `input` inside the `ul`

Comment: @Rajan Thank you very much your help. I appreciate alot. However still I couldn't get item data. that becase I didn't show whole js code I think. I update whole js scripts above. Could you look at it please? and I also add I already have $data array I woud like to add this items data into it. Thank you again your help.

Comment: @mikancode
I am still not clear what exactly you want. I have working code for your Case:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/9gthwz60/8/)

Please Update your Question or let me know what do you want. And when do you want (eg: after search or after you select any item)

Comment: @Rajan Thank you again. I need time I'm slow understading so Could you wait little more. I will contact you again. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: @Rajan Sorry for took long time. today it went good! Thank you so much. I really appreciate all of your help. Thank you again.

Comment: @mikancode You Welcome, you can Upvote answer if you want ;)